# Alloy Backbone - how to handle multi level JSON collection

Tags: backbone.js, collections, titanium, appcelerator

I am working with the new Alloy Framework on Appcelerators Titanium and I am totaly lost with its backbone handeling.

Anyway, my Problem is that I got a deep multi level json object which looks something like this:

```
[{
    title: "Bla",
    id: 0,
    content: "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..",
    articles: [
        {
            title: "bla2",
            content: "bla bla bla",
            nr: "article 1"
        },
        {
            title: "bla3",
            content: "bla baasdadla bla",
            nr: "article 2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    title: "Bla 2",
    id: 1,
    content: "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..",
    articles: [
        {
            title: "bla3",
            content: "bla bla bla",
            nr: "article 10"
        },
        {
            title: "bla4",
            content: "bla baasdadla bla",
            nr: "article 11"
        }
    ]
}];
```

And I successfully implemented it so that I got a nice TableView with the titles of the first level, but now I need access to the 2nd level, and this is where I fail at.

I got everything in a single Collection

```
    var myCollection = Alloy.createCollection('bla');
    myCollection.add(MyBigBigBigJson); // see above
    myCollection.fetch();
```

my View.xml:

```
<Alloy>
    <Collection src="bla">
    <TableView dataCollection="bla">
        <TableViewRow>
            <Label text="{title}" />
        </TableViewRow>
    </TableView>
</Alloy>
```

Now, how do I get access to, lets say the content of the 2nd level?

I tried it with:

```
    myCollection.at(0)  // first object in my collection ( where title = "Bla" )

    myCollection.at(0).articles[0].content // gives me an error and my app crashes...

    myCollection.at(0).articles // undefined
```

Well, I have no idea how I get to the articles and then to the content or title.

Anyone can help me? I hope I've made everything clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [model.get](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get):

```
myCollection.at(0).get("articles")[0].content
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that you can take is to use toJSON() on your model to get to the properties.

```
myCollection.at(0).toJSON().content
```

at(0) specifies the index of the model and you're using to JSON() to just send back the attributes. Then you can just specify the property from there.